# Evaluate Formula From Another Sheet as Current Sheet

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, eval

I'm trying to use Eval() to take some functions stored on Main and evaluate them with values from Sheet2. So far static references to Main and pure text work, but I'm having trouble referencing relative cells.

Ideally, the Main worksheet combines static and relative references and applies the function down the column to rows in a table (such that it's A7, A8, ... in this example). The single quotes are for forming SQL. Here is one of the functions I'm trying to implement.

```
=CONCATENATE(Main!$B$30, "'", A7, "', '", B7, "', '", C7, "', '", D7, "', '", E7, "', '",F7, "', '",G7, "', '",H7, "', '",I7, "', '",J7, "', '", K7, "', ",$B$4,Main!$B$35)
```

I think the problem is in my Eval function, it's not evaluating A7 as a cell value in the active sheet. I was looking into a way to change the function to something like CurrentSheet!A7, but couldn't find the proper syntax.

```
Function Eval(Ref As Range)
   Dim shCurrent As Worksheet: Set shCurrent = ActiveSheet
   Application.Volatile
   Application.ThisCell.Parent.Activate
   Eval = Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate(Ref.Formula)
   shCurrent.Activate
End Function
```

I'm referencing this Eval function in Sheet2 like this, copied down my table column where Main!$E$5 is a cell that has the above excel function in it.

```
=EVAL(Main!$E$5)
```

**ANSWER**

I took bwyn's example and modified it for my use. This is what the above excel function ended up looking like as a VB function. Sending in the row number as a parameter makes the calling function the most generic, allowing the spreadsheet master to extend the "A" and "K" values as needed in one location.

```
Function EvalInsert(rowNum As Integer)
  Dim shCurrent As Worksheet: Set shCurrent = ActiveSheet
  Dim shMain As Worksheet: Set shMain = Sheets("Main")
  Dim insertClose As String: insertClose = "'));"
  Dim openParen As String: openParen = "'"
  Dim closeParen As String: closeParen = "', "
  Application.Volatile

  Set insertOpen = shMain.Range("B30")
  Set tableId = shMain.Range("B33")
  Set TableName = shCurrent.Range("B1")
  Set insertValues = shCurrent.Range(Cells(rowNum, "A"), Cells(rowNum, "K"))

  EvalInsert = insertOpen.Value

  For Each c In insertValues.Cells
     EvalInsert = EvalInsert & openParen & c.Value & closeParen
  Next

  EvalInsert = EvalInsert & tableId & TableName & insertClose

End Function
```

I called this using

```
=EvalInsert(ROW())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your concatenate formula, it seems that only A7 changes. If this is true, then you could rewrite the Eval function as follows:

```
Function Eval(currShRelRefStr As Range)
   Dim shCurrent As Worksheet, shMain As Worksheet
   Dim mainRng As Range, currShRelRef As Range, currShStaticRef As Range
   Dim aStr As String

   Set shCurrent = ActiveSheet
   Set shMain = Sheets("Main")

   Set mainRng = shMain.Range("B30")
   Set currShRelRef = shCurrent.Range(currShRelRefStr.Value)
   Set currShStaticRef = shCurrent.Range("B3")
   aStr = "a string"

   Eval = mainRng.Value & aStr & currShRelRef.Value & currShStaticRef.Value

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I actually simplified the CONCATENATE quite a bit. It has about 10 changing cells. My original CONCATENATE is "=CONCATENATE(Main!$B$30, "'", A7, "', '", B7, "', '", C7, "', '", D7, "', '", E7, "', '",F7, "', '",G7, "', '",H7, "', '",I7, "', '",J7, "', '", K7, "', ",$B$4,Main!$B$35)". I have multiple formulas but I'm willing to create Functions for them all if needed. I've updated my main post to reflect this, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In the longer formula, only the row changes. You could input the row number, select the range of interest (A7:K7), and loop through the cells to build the concatenated string

Comment: Ok I will try that. :) I'm pretty new to VB formulas in excel, I will report back if I have success.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I was able to create my first function and it works great.